# How can I split a matrix into smaller sub-matrices?

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

I have this matrix

```
x =

 5     5     3     3     2    
 5     5     2     2     2     
 0     5     5     4     4     
 0     0     0     0     0    
 0     0     0     0     0     
 2     0     3     0     0
```

How can I reshape that matrix into :

```
x1 = 5     5     3     3     2    
     5     5     2     2     2
x2 = 0     5     5     4     4     
     0     0     0     0     0
x3 = 0     0     0     0     0     
     2     0     3     0     0
```

Thank you for every responses...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
x1 = x(1:2,:)
x2 = x(3:4,:)
x3 = x(5:6,:)
```

Comment: Note: This is almost never a good idea in MATLAB. Also, the solution is cumbersome to scale if the dimensions change.

Comment: i did change the range of rows used variables so the dimensions not change, so i give the code some combinations
thank you for your help, I appreciate and will try your code @Stewie Griffin :)

Answer (score 2):

**[Don't do this!](http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_create_variables_A1.2C_A2.2C....2CA10_in_a_loop.3F)** It's never a good idea! Are you planning on [combining this with `eval`? Don't!](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html) If you need to have them separated, either put them in different layers in a 3 dimensional matrix, or use cell arrays.

## 3D-array:

```
permute(reshape(x.', 5, 2, []), [2 1 3])
ans =
ans(:,:,1) =
   5   5   3   3   2
   5   5   2   2   2
ans(:,:,2) =
   0   5   5   4   4
   0   0   0   0   0
ans(:,:,3) =
   0   0   0   0   0
   2   0   3   0   0
```

**Breakdown**

```
permute(reshape(x.',5,2,[]), [2 1 3])
                x.'                    % Transpose x
        reshape(x.',5,2,[])            % Reshape x.' to have 5 rows, 2 cols, []-layers
permute(reshape(x.',5,2,[]), [2 1 3])  % Permute the new 3-dimensional matrix
                                       % permute(mat,[2 1 3]) will transpose each layer of
                                       % the matrix giving us the result we want
```

## Cell array:

```
mat2cell(x, [2, 2, 2])
ans = 
{
  [1,1] =
     5   5   3   3   2
     5   5   2   2   2
  [2,1] =
     0   5   5   4   4
     0   0   0   0   0
  [3,1] =
     0   0   0   0   0
     2   0   3   0   0
}
```